# What does type constructor in type theory correspond to in category theory?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

If types themselves correspond to object or for example Unit type corresponds to terminal object, then what does type constructor correspond to in a category?

Comment: In general, it corresponds to a function on objects of the category, nothing else. Sometimes it happens to be a functor, e.g. when it comes from a (co)limit.

Comment: The unit type corresponds to the *terminal* object, not the initial object.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type constructor generally corresponds to the existence of some limits or colimits, or some more elaborate object defined by a universal property, in the category. So product types correspond to pullbacks in the category, or perhaps just products if your type theory doesn't contexts. Function types correspond to internal homs in the sense of Cartesian closure, and dependent products correspond to relative internal homs in the sense of local Cartesian closure. And so on.

**EDIT:** A natural numbers type is interpreted categorically as an object $N$ together with an endomorphism $s$ and a term $0:*\to N$ initial with respect to this structure. The usual description of a natural numbers type may not immediately make this apparent, but if you require $sn$ for every term in *context* $A|n:N$ then $s$ is simply $s\mathrm{id}$ for the identity term-in-context $N|\mathrm{id}:N$.

Comment: Thanks, what I am confused about (and the reason I brought up above question) is that relations like succ (n) are not transitive hence in a way can not be composed. And since category theory mandates the morphisms to compose, then how is something like natural number and succ(n) represented in categorically?

Comment: @DerekElkins Thanks, I hope it's a bit more readable now. Type theory's not something I write down much so I'm sure it's still not ideal.